# How to change jQuery click action based on browser screen size or type

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a responsive site running Twitter Bootstrap and I have a toggle action with drops a contact form down from the top of the page when using clicks an image. If the user has a screen size below 660px wide I want to change the click action to a mailto. What's the best way to detect the screen size and change this toggle to a mailto?

```
$("#contact-tab").toggle(function() {
    $('#contactme').attr("src", "/wp-content/themes/wordpress-bootstrap-child/img/close_btn.png");
    $('#contact-form-wrapper').slideToggle(
        function() {
        } 
    );
}, function() {
        $('#contactme').attr("src", "/wp-content/themes/wordpress-bootstrap-child/img/contact_me.png");
        $('#contact-form-wrapper').slideToggle(
            function() {
            } 
        );
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be something like:

```
$(function(){
   var winWidth = $(window).width();

   if(winWidth < 660){
      $("#contact-tab").click(function(){
         window.open('mailto: ... ');
      });
   } else {
      //go toggle ...
   }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

`$('html').width()` should tell you the screen width